# Understanding 殴られてやる

Tags: grammar, subsidiary-verbs

> 口の中を切った血を吐き捨てて立ち上がる。思いの外にダメージの少ない、淀みのない動き。
>
> 「経験上、実際に聞くまで誰も納得しないから言わないだけだ。時間を無駄にしたくない」
>
> 「あァ？　おまえ何言って、」
>
> 「そのうち話す。……それと、」
>
> 言うなりシンはライデンの顔面をぶん殴った。
>
> 小柄な体軀で至極コンパクトな振りで、おそろしく効いた。体重の移動と力の伝達が無駄一つなく適切だからで、なす術もなく殴り倒されて頭がくらくらした。
>
> 「**殴られてやる**謂れはない。おれは手加減はしないが、それでいいならかかってこい」
>
> 何をこの、と今度は本気で殴りかかって。

86─エイティシックス─
安里アサト

ライデン hits シン for some reason, and シン hits back.

Why is the bold てやる used there? Isn’t it the same as てあげる (do something for you)? I don’t understand why it is used after the passive form. I think 殴られる謂れはない is enough.

Answer (score 4):

There is a discernable difference there, between 殴られる謂れはない and 殴られてやる謂れはない.

When you say 殴られる, you are making a statement matter-of-factly. When you say 殴られてやる, you are stating intent, making clear that your own **volition and agency** are involved: you are **actively allowing** 殴られる to happen. Also やる is crude あげる, serving to lifting the speaker's own position. 殴られてやる: I let you beat me up as a favor. I will go easy on you.

- 殴られる謂れはない
  There's no reason/it's unwarranted for me to get beat up.
  (Okay fine, but 1. maybe nobody wants to beat you up; 2. maybe it's not up to you)
- 殴られてやる謂れはない
  There's no reason/it's unwarranted for me to let people beat me up.
  (I am hereby announcing my own intention which is I won't allow myself to get beat up and I will take action accordingly)

And that's why the character then says おれは手加減はしない (I'm not gonna go easy on you/I'm not holding back/I'm not pulling any punches)

It's like in English how people say, "I'm not going to sit here and **have** my name tarnished by detractors."

By the same token, 振られてやる means "I am going to **let** you (someone else) break up with me." "I am **allowing** that to happen."

> 振られてやるさ、振られてやるさ、邪魔なんかしたくない ([研ナオコ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpvZkI70_Bs))
> I will let you dump me/ I will let you dump me/ Cuz I don't wanna be in the way

Comment: Thank you. So can 殴らせてやる be used in the original context? According to your explanation, both 殴らせてやる and 殴られてやる seem to mean the same thing.

Comment: @chinoalpha I wouldn't say they are the same. They are indeed close in meaning, but still different enough to effect meaningful preferences. 殴らせてやる sounds stronger, and is more than "going easy". It is like standing there and asking the other party to strike oneself.